# How to get property types

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

There is possibility to get properties for some model node:

```
model.getProperties(nodeId, /*success handler*/, /*error handler*/)
```

Result is something like this:
[properties list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7oeot.png)

Property description has field "type" that looks like ID. There can I find info about property types? How can I determine is it numerable or alphabetical?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the type values from the C++ code that performs properties extraction:

```
enum AttributeType {

  /* Numeric types */
  Unknown                 = 0,
    Boolean,
    Integer,
    Double,

    /* Special types */
    BLOB                    = 10,
    DbKey, /* reprensets a link to another object in the database, using database internal ID */

    /* String types */
    String                  = 20,
    LocalizableString,
    DateTime,       /* ISO 8601 date */
    GeoLocation,    /* LatLonHeight - ISO6709 Annex H string, e.g: "+27.5916+086.5640+8850/" for Mount Everest */
    Position        /* "x y z w" space separated string representing vector with 2,3 or 4 elements*/
};
```

Comment: 1) Is it in your plans to make possibility to get this information from some API?

Comment: 2) How can I get additional information for types? For example, precision for double?