# Is there a mapping information for dataType of property?

Tags: autodesk-forge

I'm a developer using Autodesk Forge.
Now I got attribute data from SQLite downloaded by Forge API.
I'd like to insert these data into *Elasticsearch* so I want to know the data type of each value.
In the attribute data, I can find dataType but it has an integer value.
I can't judge them by numbers.

Is there mapping information for the dataType field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check [How to get property types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46619701/how-to-get-property-types/46621679#46621679), but not all of them are supported.

```
enum AttributeType {

  /* Numeric types */
  Unknown                 = 0,
    Boolean,
    Integer,
    Double,

    /* Special types */
    BLOB                    = 10,
    DbKey, /* reprensets a link to another object in the database, using database internal ID */

    /* String types */
    String                  = 20,
    LocalizableString,
    DateTime,       /* ISO 8601 date */
    GeoLocation,    /* LatLonHeight - ISO6709 Annex H string, e.g: "+27.5916+086.5640+8850/" for Mount Everest */
    Position        /* "x y z w" space separated string representing vector with 2,3 or 4 elements*/
};
```

Comment: @MASAMIKI, And this is a definitions table used internally which has not been documented. It may subject to change. you may use on your own risk. Thank you for understanding.

Comment: Oh, I see..., It's a critical issue for my system. I try to have other considerations.
Thank you.