# Data types in attributes table in SQLite database from Model Derivative

Tags: database, sqlite, types, properties, autodesk-model-derivative

Is there any documentation what the values in column `data_type` of `_objects_attr` table from the *SQLite* model properties database returned by the Model Derivative's `{urn}/manifest` endpoint mean?
As you see below the values in the `data_type` column are `20`, `11`, `1`, `2`:
[`_objects_attr` table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BT65T.png)

I tried to find out from the *SQLite* model properties database what data type a particular attribute is but could not find any meaningful answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check [How to get property types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46619701/how-to-get-property-types/46621679#46621679) instead.

BTW, could you share your use case for using the Sqlite Property DB with us? If it's not publicly sharable, please consider sending that to `aps (DOT) help (AT) autodesk (DOT) com`, our support channel.

```
enum AttributeType {

  /* Numeric types */
  Unknown                 = 0,
    Boolean,
    Integer,
    Double,

    /* Special types */
    BLOB                    = 10,
    DbKey, /* reprensets a link to another object in the database, using database internal ID */

    /* String types */
    String                  = 20,
    LocalizableString,
    DateTime,       /* ISO 8601 date */
    GeoLocation,    /* LatLonHeight - ISO6709 Annex H string, e.g: "+27.5916+086.5640+8850/" for Mount Everest */
    Position        /* "x y z w" space separated string representing vector with 2,3 or 4 elements*/
};
```